# Defining @Annotations shows full package path instead of the @Annotation

Tags: spring, rest, controller, annotations

how can i possibly fix this i don't want to see the full package path.. help [image]

I have not found info regarding this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top, add this:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class RestController
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your class is named "RestController" same as the interface you are trying to implement by @RestController annotation